# Django: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to get some data from a payload using a webhook, in the response that I sent along side I added the meta data that should return with the payload and this is  how I did it (*code below*), if you take a close look at the keys, there I one called `meta`, now I am trying to get some of the data that is in the meta from my webhook view like this:

**views.py webhook**

```
@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook(request):
    payload = request.body
    order_id = payload['meta']['order_id']
    print(order_id)
    return HttpResponse("testing...")
```

**Sending the reponse to the payment gateway**

```
@csrf_exempt
def process_payment(request, name, email, amount, order_id):
    auth_token = "FLWSECK_TEST-9efb9ee17d8afe40c6c890294a1163de-X"
    hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}
    data = {
            "tx_ref":''+str(math.floor(1000000 + random.random()*9000000)),
            "amount":amount,
            "currency":"USD",
            "order_id":order_id,
            "redirect_url":f"http://localhost:3000/service-detail/booking/confirmation/{order_id}",
            "payment_options":"card",
            "meta":{
                "order_id":order_id,
                "consumer_id":23,
                "consumer_mac":"92a3-912ba-1192a"
            },
            "customer":{
                "email":email,
                "name":name,
                "order_id":order_id
            },
            "customizations":{
                "title":"ForecastFaceoff",
                "description":"Leading Political Betting Platform",
                "logo":"https://i.im.ge/2022/08/03m/FELzix.stridearn-high-quality-logo-circle.jpg"
                }
            }
    url = ' https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/payments'
    response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=hed)
    response=response.json()
    link=response['data']['link']
    return redirect(link)
```

payload

```
{
  "event": "charge.completed",
  "data": {
    "id": 4136234873,
    "tx_ref": "6473247093",
    "flw_ref": "FLW-MOCK-b33e86ab2342316fec664110e8eb842a3c2f956",
    "device_fingerprint": "df38c8854324598c54e16feacc65348a5e446",
    "amount": 152,
    "currency": "USD",
    "charged_amount": 152,
    "app_fee": 5.78,
    "merchant_fee": 0,
    "processor_response": "Approved. Successful",
    "auth_model": "VBVSECUREertrCODE",
    "ip": "52.209.154.143",
    "narration": "CARD Transaction ",
    "status": "successful",
    "payment_type": "card",
    "created_at": "2023-02-06T11:19:45.000Z",
    "account_id": 685622,
    "customer": {
      "id": 1970338,
      "name": "destiny ",
      "phone_number": null,
      "email": "******@gmail.com",
      "created_at": "2023-02-06T11:19:45.000Z"
    },
    "card": {
      "first_6digits": "653188",
      "last_4digits": "2340",
      "issuer": "MASTERCARD  CREDIT",
      "country": "NG",
      "type": "MASTERCARD",
      "expiry": "49/32"
    }
  },
  "event.type": "CARD_TRANSACTION"
}
```

The metadata is not even showing in the payload, must it show up there in the payload  before I can grab the data that is sent with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta data is not in the `payload` dictionary. At first try to extract the data key from the payload like this:

```py
@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook(request):
    payload = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    data = payload.get("data")
    if data:
        order_id = data.get("meta", {}).get("order_id")
        print(order_id)
    return HttpResponse("just testing")
```

### Edit:

The error message
as you described above in comment `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) indicates that json.loads()` is expecting a JSON string as input.

It may be possible that request body is empty. You can check that by printing the `request.body` before calling `json.loads()`.

Try this:

```py
@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook(request):
    payload = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    data = payload.get("data")
    if data and "meta" in data:
        order_id = data.get("meta").get("order_id")
        print(order_id)
    else:
        print("Meta key not found in data or data not found in payload")
        print(payload)
    return HttpResponse("just testing")
```

It would tell you whether the `"meta"` is present in `data` dictionary or not and also prints `payload` dict at the end.

Comment: thanks for your response, it still does not get the order_id, i have added some print statement to print the, payload, data and order_id, it returns None for the order_id, i manually added 1 to the value of order_id to see if it would return 1, but it still returns none, turns out it is still not getting the meta dictionary. Please do you have any idea on what can be done next?

Comment: @DestinyFranks let me check it, and if found something, I'd tell you :)

Comment: alright, that would be really appreciated brother

Comment: @DestinyFranks Make sure the key "meta" is present in the "data" dictionary by checking `if "meta" in data` returns True. Also try to print the entire `payload` dictionary.

Comment: Yes that is the issue, when i print the whle payload, the ``meta` key and it values are not showing in the payload, and there is no useful information on the docs on how to return the `meta` values back to us in the payload.

Comment: @DestinyFranks See edited answer at the end, are you sure that `meta` key and it values are not showing, then you should at platform's support team to clarify the issue. I really don't know now.

Comment: It is not yet solved, i tried another payment method called paystack and it happened that paystack returns the meta with the payload, so the error was obviously from flutterwave, and i have contacted the api support team to look in the issue and resolve as you told me to do, as soon as it solved; i'll update you. thanks aton

Answer (score 0):

request.body is byte not a dict, so you need to load the string as JSON.

```
payload = json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: I added the line it displaying this nev error `JSONDecodeError at /api/webhook/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`,  what can i do about this please?

Comment: Are you getting the payload in request.body? print it to make sure that it is received probably.

Comment: okay, let me do that

Comment: After sending the reqeust again and printing the payload, i get the payload in terminal but the error still persist

Comment: try this:  payload = request.body,  print(payload), payload= json.loads(payload)

Comment: , separate lines.

Comment: Okay, let me do that